# I am migrating spring boot 2.7.3 version to spring boot 3.0.2 where SQSConnectionFactory is not compatible with spring boot 3.0.2 version

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, java-17

below is configuration class where we are creating bean of DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory class

```
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver;

import javax.jms.Session;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfiguration {
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(SQSConnectionFactory con)                                    {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

gradle.properties file where we have given all versions

```
sqsVersion=1.0.8
#sqsVersion=2.0.1
stsVersion=1.11.759
awsCoreVersion=1.11.759
#awsCoreVersion=2.0.1
hibernateVersion=6.1.6.Final
secretsManagerJdbcVersion=1.0.5
secretsManagerCacheVersion=1.0.1
springdocOpenApiUiVersion=1.6.6
ssmVersion=1.11.755
```

method  setConnectionFactory() is not accepting SQSConnectionFactory object

I have tried with different version but no luck
Please suggest appropriate version of SQSConnectionFactory which can work with spring boot 3.0.2
version

Comment: AWS SDK for Java v2 works with JDK 17/Spring Boot 3.

Answer (score 1):

The **AWS SDK for Java V1** is not recommended to use as per the guidelines on the AWS Page here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples (look at the table near end of the page)

The recommended version is **[AWS SDK for Java V2](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html)**. Here is the **SQSConnectionFactory** class you want to use in V2:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/SQSConnectionFactory.java

You can use AWS Java API v2 with Spring BOOT 3 that requires JDK 17. I have verfified that **AWS SDK Java v2** works with Spring Boot 3 using a custom project. My Spring BOOT 3 project's POM is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>aws-spring3</groupId>
    <artifactId>ItemTrackerRDSRest3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ItemTrackerRDSRest3</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot 3 and AWS</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.14</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ses</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdsdata</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>protocol-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

Now I am able to use **AWS SDK for Java V2** API in a Spring BOOT 3 project. My database example successfully queries data from an Amazon Aurora Serverless database.

[image]